# Use VBA to refresh pivot tables

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I am working on a project, where I dump data on a monthly basis in Sheet1. In my sheet analysis, I have three pivot tables summarizing this data using certain filter, which should remain unchanged even if the raw data changes.

I use the following VBA code to update the pivot tables after the data dump.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analysis")

.PivotTables("PivotTable1").RefreshTable
.PivotTables("PivotTable2").RefreshTable

End With

Sheets("Output").Activate

End Sub
```

The problem is, whenever I have a new data dump in Sheet 1 and then run the code, I get the following message: *There is already data in [Dokument1]Analysis. Do you want to replace it?* After this the output from the pivot tables is wrong and the supposedly static pivot filters are no longer there.

I made sure that there is more than enough space between the pivot tables and there cannot be any overlaps. I have had this problem for a long time and do not know how to solve it, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using `ActiveSheet` is a bad idea. This is because at any given point, `ActiveSheet` could not be the sheet you want to reference. Try qualifying your sheet (i.e. `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("Sheet1")`). Also, if you want to refresh all pivot tables on a sheet, I would just iterate through the pivot table on the sheet. This way if you ever change the names of pivot tables, your `Refresh` will still work

Comment: Do you get the same issue when using `PivotTable.PivotCache.Refresh` instead of `PivotTable.RefreshTable`?  Do the Values you have filtered on still exist?  What are the states of the "Include new items in manual filter" and "Show items with no data" settings in the PivotField?

Comment: @Zac Roger that I changed that!
@Chronocidal Thanks for your response! I tried `PivotTable.PivotCache.Refresh` and the problem persists unfortunately. The values I filter still exist. BOTH "Include New items in manual filter" and "show items with no data" are NOT checked. Any ideas? thanks again!!

Comment: Can you post your updated code?

Comment: @Zac updated code posted! Yet the issue is still there. The pivot table do not update correctly?

Answer (score 2):

This is a nice way to loop through all worksheets and refresh all pivot tables:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable

For Each ws In wb.Sheets
  For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
    pt.PivotCache.Refresh
  Next pt
Next ws
```

Of course, you can easily impose limits if you want to exclude any worksheets or pivot tables.  The nice thing about this is not only does it do all tables in blocks (by sheet), but if tables are added, removed or renamed, it doesn't crash when looking for specific tables.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use ActiveSheet. In my opinion is better to use create a with statement refers to the sheet you want and use refresh all instead of one by one.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        .RefreshAll

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

as of excel 2016 (i think, certainly 2019)

```
ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
```